# Elm: how to use an iframe

Tags: elm

I want to render an `iframe` given a `String` input.  For example, I have some string of HTML like this:

```
str = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>HELLO ELM</body></html>"
```

In JS I would do this by setting `innerHtml` on the `iframe`.

For now, I'm trying to just get the `iframe` to render anything at all, but haven't had success.  I'm trying this sort of thing:

```
iframe 
    []
    [ body [] [ div [][text "hi"], div [][text "hi"] ] ]
```

Once I get it working with a list of HTML nodes, I'll move onto making it work with a string.  What I'm looking for would be some kind of `stringToHtml: String -> List Html` method.

Any help or suggestions for getting started with iframes in elm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`srcdoc`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-srcdoc) attribute of an iframe to set the html from an html string, like so:

```elm
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (srcdoc)

main =
  div [ ]
    [ div [] [ text "Outside the iframe" ]
    , iframe
      [ srcdoc "<div>Inside the iframe</div>" ]
      []
    ]
```

(IE and Edge do not currently support `srcdoc` but there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/jugglinmike/srcdoc-polyfill))

In the end, though, that's a rather brittle solution because it bypasses the Virtual DOM. At this time, there appears no other way to manipulate iframe content within the Virtual DOM. Could your content instead be stored in another page and referenced through the iframe `src` attribute?