# How insert html into iframe with CycleJS

Tags: javascript, iframe, cyclejs

With vanilla JavaScript, I would do the following to add an `h1` tag to the iframe body:

```
var doc = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document;
doc.write('<h1>Hello</h1>');
```

How can I do this with CycleJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 introduces the `iframe` attribute `srcdoc` that takes a string of HTML:

```
import {iframe, makeDOMDriver} from '@cycle/dom';

// later

iframe({attrs: {srcdoc: '<h1>Hello</h1>'}})
```

Apparently this does not work in IE or Edge without a [polyfill](https://github.com/jugglinmike/srcdoc-polyfill), as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34540652/2743458).

---

Of course there's the old trusty:

```
iframe({attrs: {src: 'myiframe.html'}})
```